# QML interaction with CPP : property double results in NaN

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Here is my QML file that is a simple Rectangle where I want to display double values excerpted from my cpp code (yaw, roll and pitch).

tilt.qml :

```
  import QtQuick 2.5
  Rectangle {
    id: myTilt
    width: 100
    height: 80
    color: "grey"
    border.color: "black"
    anchors.margins: 15
    property double yaw: 1.0 ;
    property double roll: 0 ;
    property double pitch: 0;


    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            parent.color =  Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1);
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: tilt
        text: qsTr("Tilt :")
        anchors.margins: 3
        anchors.top: page.top
        anchors.left: page.left
    }

    Text {
        id: yaw
        text: qsTr("Yaw : ") + Math.abs(yaw)
        anchors.margins: 5
        anchors.top: tilt.bottom
        anchors.left: tilt.left
    }
    Text {
        id: roll
        text: qsTr("Roll : ") + roll
        anchors.margins: 0
        anchors.top: yaw.bottom
        anchors.left: yaw.left
    }
    Text {
        id: pitch
        text: qsTr("Pitch : ") + pitch
        anchors.margins: 0
        anchors.top: roll.bottom
        anchors.left: roll.left
    }
 }
```

Here is what I tryied in order to link my cpp values to the qml code. 
myTilt is a QQuickItem.

```
void OpenGLManager::build_qml(QQuickWidget *tilt_qml) {
myTilt = tilt_qml->rootObject();

myTilt->setProperty("yaw", tilt[0]);
myTilt->setProperty("pitch", tilt[1]);
myTilt->setProperty("roll", tilt[2]);
}

void OpenGLManager::setDroneTilt(QList<double> yaw, QList<double> pitch, QList<double> roll)
{
tilt = QVector3D(10, 20, 30) ; 
myTilt->setProperty("yaw", tilt[0]);
myTilt->setProperty("pitch", tilt[1]);
myTilt->setProperty("roll", tilt[2]);
}
```

I'm loading this qml file as source for a QQuickWidget designed in QtDesigner. 
The rectangle displays fine but instead of the values I want, I get NaN for Math.abs(yaw) and QQuickText(0x2a29100) for roll and pitch.

I'm using Qt5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Text {
        id: yaw
        text: qsTr("Yaw : ") + Math.abs(yaw)
        anchors.margins: 5
        anchors.top: tilt.bottom
        anchors.left: tilt.left
    }
```

I wonder what can go wrong...

It's an ID of the text element.

Also, there is a general practice: never use QML objects from C++ code. So, don't do things like  `myTilt = tilt_qml->rootObject();` and `myTilt->setProperty(...);`. Create a C++ class instead and make it usable from QML.